# Export specific strings from xml to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, xml

[XML Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3iF4.png)

I have got a item list xml file for a game server, and I need to insert item names, id's and type of the item into a mysql server. I have provided 4 examples of situations, first has isstaffitem="true", second has iscashitem="true" third iscashitem="false" and fourth has nothing regarding item type. Now what I need is to read the id="string", name="string" and type of the item and insert into database. If it's staff item, set type as staff, if cash item set type to cash and set regular if something else.

How can I do that php ? I am trying with `$xml = simplexml_load_string($_POST['zitem']);` but can't get it work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some example code. I created a simple HTML-form, with a textarea to input the XML-code. After hitting "Submit", the PHP-script is triggered (server method = post). Connect to your database (example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)). Parse the XML-string as a [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (gives you more options then simple_xml). Insert each item in your xml into MySQL.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Make connection to database first
    // example from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Use DomDocument (more options / flexibility)
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($_POST['zitem']);
    $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ITEM');
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // The attributed in the XML item "ITEM", can be retrieved by using $item->getAttribute('nameofattribute')
        $id = $item->getAttribute('id');
        $name = $item->getAttribute('name');
        $mesh_name = $item->getAttribute('mesh_name');

        // Some logic, see for yourself.
        $cashitem = false;
        if ($item->getAttribute('iscashitem') == true) {
            $cashitem = true;
        }

        $staffitem = false;
        if ($item->getAttribute('isstaffitem') == true) {
            $staffitem = true;
        }

        // Insert the item from XML into MySQL-table
        $sql = "
              INSERT INTO Items
                (id, name, mesh_name, cashitem, staffitem)
              VALUES (
                '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($id) . "',
                '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($name) . "',
                '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($mesh_name) . "',
                'somevaluehere',
                'somevaluehere'
              )";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }    
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="zitem"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit your XML file" />
</form>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't the `somevaluehere` be the `$cashitem` and `$staffitem` variables?

Comment: Depends on what he wants in his database. But yes. Only not as php booleans, I assume.